# Query JSON Documents using SQLite

Tags: python, json, database, sqlite, database-design

How could I design a database schema to store JSON? How can I write a query to extract all movies directed by Adam Smith? How can I modify database schema to additionally store JSON with nested objects (plus other changes)? etc.

```
{
    "name": "The Parent Trap",
    "released": "29 July 1998",
    "imdb": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120783/",
    "rating": "PG"
    "director": {
        "name": "Adam Smith"
        "dob": "December 8, 1949"
    }
}
```

I would like to write some library for this task, Query JSON Documents stored in Sqlite, in python, but I am curious how to approach this problem correctly. Any suggestions are highly welcome?

Comment: You want to store hierarchical data in a relational database and then use SQL to query it?  I'm afraid you'll need to give some examples of usage for your question to make sense...

Comment: Does your Python have SQLite's [JSON extension](http://www.sqlite.org/json1.html)?

Comment: @CL. Is there any python binding for JSON1 extension?

Comment: Such an extension would be part of the SQLite library (which is compiled into Python), or a loadable module. Python bindings are not needed because it implements only SQL functions.